# What is the best way to generate events from Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I have a series of jenkins pipeline jobs to move Apps to Cloud Foundry. My client application need to be able to listen to all the updates of a push. I.e. apart from getting text logs, i need other events like Git repo cloned, cloud foundry logged in, App pushed.

One crud way of doing this is to submit POST requests to an event server from a shell script(Curl). However, I think it is unlikely that such a functionality does not exist already on Jenkins(either through a plugin or something like that).

I need an advice from best practices point of view.

Thanks.

Comment: Why can you just push all the build logs (Console Output) to some tool like Kibana or  Splunk.

Comment: @mdabdullah Thanks for the comment. Could you elaborate? Would a tool like kibana auto-detect important events from the logs?

Comment: Yes it can `auto-detect` if you configure `regex` alerts to send emails, create dashboard etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As commented by mdabdullah. But this needs a person to set up kibana or splunk. (I did not try this).
2. Statistics gatherer plugin
   https://plugins.jenkins.io/statistics-gatherer/
3. Jenkins notification plugin
   https://plugins.jenkins.io/notification/

Both 2,3 are available plugins in the Jenkins community. They need to configured for server endpoints before use.